# How do you navigate from a sub component in Angular Dart 2?

Tags: routes, dart, angular-dart

I have three components: `Summary`, `CategorySummary` and `Category`. `CategorySummary` is a subcomponent of `Summary`. I've got routes defined for `Summary` and `Category` and can navigate between the two of them via `[routerLink]`.

The problem is that I can't navigate from `CategorySummary` (the sub-component) to `Category`. If I put `[routerLink]` in the template I see the correct URL when I hover over the link. Clicking the link correctly updates the URL in the browser, but the page doesn't change.

The symptoms are the same if I try to navigate via `router.navigate`.

How do I navigate from a subcomponent?

Here is the code for `CategorySummary`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';
import 'package:PublicSite/models.dart';
import 'package:PublicSite/pie_chart_component/pie_chart_component.dart';

@Component(
        selector: 'category-summary',
        styleUrls: const ['category_summary_component.css'],
        templateUrl: 'category_summary_component.html',
        directives: const [PieChartComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES])
class CategorySummaryComponent {
  final Router _router;

  @Input()
  PromiseCategoryCount categoryCount;

  CategorySummaryComponent(this._router);

  Future gotoCategory() {
    return _router.navigate([
        'Category',
        {'id': categoryCount.Category}
      ]);
  }
}
```

---

#### Update

Tracing through the router code I found that when I call _router.navigate from my subcomponent the router doesn't have an outlet: _outlet is null. A clue, but what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute paths like

```
  Future gotoCategory() {
    return _router.navigate([
        '/Summary', 'Category',
        {'id': categoryCount.Category}
      ]);
  }
```

or

```
  Future gotoCategory() {
    return _router.navigate([
        '/Summary/Category',
        {'id': categoryCount.Category}
      ]);
  }
```

or relative paths like

```
  Future gotoCategory() {
    return _router.navigate([
        '../Category',
        {'id': categoryCount.Category}
      ]);
  }
```

Comment: No dice. "/Category" and "/Summary" are top level routes. There is no path to "/Summary/Category". It all works except when I try to navigate to "/Category" from a subcomponent on "/Summary". FWIW, the third example results in this message in the console: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Link "[../Category, {id: health}]" has too many "../" segments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be more than one component having `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` defined. Once the extras were removed things started behaving.